# Introductory statistics

Tags: statistics

This is a very very simple question, yet 3 hours later i'm going nuts so i decided to ask here. Please bear with me:

Given: $$N=10, \sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2=84, \sum_{i=1}^N X_i=20$$

I'm supposed to find the variance:

The formula is $$S^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\mu)^2}{N}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2-2x_i\mu+\mu^2}{N}=\frac{84-2(20*2)+4}{10}=0.8$$

However, the solution says it should be 4.4.

I know this is quite simple and I must have made an extremely stupid mistake somewhere but it's been 3 hours I still don't know where....Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^2=\sum_{i=1}^N(x_i^2-2\mu x_i+\mu^2)=\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i^2-2\mu\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i+\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^N\mu^2}$$$$=84-(2\times2\times20)+\color{red}{(N\times\mu^2)}=84-80+(10\times4)=44.$$